# Display dates in xAxis of an Android line graph

Tags: java, android, date, graph

I'm trying to display some values that I retrieve from my Firestore collection documents in two different line graphs. I use the jjoe64 library but my app crashes when I press the button to generate the graphs. [Firestore database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6hHGr.png) Here's my fragment's code:

```
package com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons;


import android.content.Context;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.GraphView;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.LegendRenderer;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.Viewport;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.helper.StaticLabelsFormatter;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.DataPoint;
import com.jjoe64.graphview.series.LineGraphSeries;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class TimelineFragment extends Fragment {

    private FirebaseFirestore firebaseFirestore;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private EditText regionText;
    private Button regionChooseBtn;


    public TimelineFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_timeline, container, false);

        regionText = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.selectRegionText);
        regionChooseBtn = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.chooseRegionBtn);

        firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        firebaseFirestore = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        regionChooseBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String select_text = regionText.getText().toString();
                if (!select_text.isEmpty()) {

                    if(firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser() != null) {

                        firebaseFirestore.collection("PuckData").whereEqualTo("region", select_text)
                                .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    List<String> dates_list = new ArrayList<>();
                                    List<Integer> temperature_list = new ArrayList<>();
                                    List<Integer> light_list = new ArrayList<>();
                                    for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                                        int light = document.getLong("light").intValue();
                                        int temperature = document.getLong("temperature").intValue();
                                        Date date = document.getDate("timestamp");
                                        SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy-HH:mm");
                                        String stringDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);

                                        temperature_list.add(temperature);
                                        light_list.add(light);
                                        dates_list.add(stringDate);
                                    }

                                    GraphView graph = view.findViewById(R.id.graph);
                                    LineGraphSeries<DataPoint> series = new LineGraphSeries<>(generateLightList(dates_list, light_list));
                                    graph.addSeries(series);
                                    Log.d("LIST", "DATES: " + dates_list.toString());
                                    Log.d("LIST", "TEMPS: " + temperature_list.toString());
                                    Log.d("LIST", "LIGHTS: " + light_list.toString());
                                } else {
                                    Log.d("PUCK", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                                }
                            }
                        });

                    }
                }

                regionText.setText("");

                final InputMethodManager imm = (InputMethodManager) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
                imm.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getView().getWindowToken(), 0);
            }
        });
        return view;
    }

    private DataPoint[] generateLightList(List<String> dateList, List<Integer> lightList) {
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[dateList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < dateList.size(); i++) {
            DataPoint v = new DataPoint(Double.parseDouble(dateList.get(i)), lightList.get(i));
            values[i] = v;
        }
        return values;
    }

    private DataPoint[] generateTemperatureList(List<String> dateList, List<Integer> temperatureList) {
        DataPoint[] values = new DataPoint[dateList.size()];
        for (int i = 0; i < dateList.size(); i++) {
            DataPoint v = new DataPoint(Double.parseDouble(dateList.get(i)), temperatureList.get(i));
            values[i] = v;
        }
        return values;
    }

}
```

This is my model PuckData class:

```
package com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons.model;

import com.google.firebase.firestore.ServerTimestamp;

import java.util.Date;
/**
 * Created by drodo on 25-Mar-18.
 */

public class PuckData {

    public int light, temperature;
    public double battery;
    public Date timestamp;


    public PuckData() {}

    public PuckData(int light, int temperature, double battery, Date timestamp) {
        this.light = light;
        this.temperature = temperature;
        this.battery = battery;
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

    public double getLight() {
        return light;
    }

    public void setLight(int light) {
        this.light = light;
    }

    public double getTemperature() {
        return temperature;
    }

    public void setTemperature(int temperature) {
        this.temperature = temperature;
    }

    public double getBattery() {
        return battery;
    }

    public void setBattery(double battery) {
        this.battery = battery;
    }

    public Date getTimestamp() {
        return timestamp;
    }

    public void setTimestamp(Date timestamp) {
        this.timestamp = timestamp;
    }

}
```

I want to to display in the first graph xAxis(dates) and yAxis(light) and dates-temperature in the other graph. My app crashes when I press the button in order to pick only the region that the user typed in the edit text and this is what I get:

> java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "07/07/18-04:50"
>           at java.lang.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1306)
>           at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:547)
>           at com.example.drodo.diamondbeacons.TimelineFragment.generateLightList(TimelineFragment.java:118)

Comment: Did you use your search engine? Is this a duplicate of [Android: GraphView How do I implement time in the X axis?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21217635/android-graphview-how-do-i-implement-time-in-the-x-axis)

Answer (score 1):

The error message is quite clear. You're calling `Double.parseDouble(dateList.get(i))`, but `dateList.get(i)` is not a number but a string of format `"07/07/18-04:50"`.

My guess is that you're trying to call [this constructor of `DataPoint`](https://github.com/jjoe64/GraphView/blob/master/src/main/java/com/jjoe64/graphview/series/DataPoint.java#L41): `public DataPoint(Date x, double y) {...`, which means you should parse the string into its corresponding data.

```
Date date=new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy-HH:mm").parse(dateList.get(i));
DataPoint v = new DataPoint(date, lightList.get(i));
```